# Ansible vars_prompt and msg usage prints hello world

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Based on input from Zeitounator I have updated the original question.  The following works

```
root@devenv:~/scripts/uia# cat addVlanTest.yml
---
- name: PLAY 111 Add Vlan ;
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: vlanIdToAdd
      prompt: vlan ID to add
      private: no
      default: "50"
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug task Take 1"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: vlanIdToAdd
    - name: "Debug task Take 2"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ vlanIdToAdd }}"
    - name: "Debug task Take 3"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Creating vlan {{ vlanIdToAdd }}"
```

Correct:
msg: "Creating vlan {{ vlanIdToAdd }}"

Incorrect:
msg:"Creating vlan {{ vlanIdToAdd }}"

What is the scope ?  Variables do not survive after plays.  If you need to use it in a different play save it.

```
root@devenv:~/scripts/uia# cat addVlanTest.yml
---
- name: PLAY 111 Add Vlan ;
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: vlanIdToAdd
      prompt: vlan ID to add
      private: no
      default: "50"
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug vars Take 1"
      debug:
        var=vlanIdToAdd
    - name: "Debug vars Take 1"
      set_fact:
        new_vlan_id="{{ vlanIdToAdd }}"
- name: PLAY 112 Add Vlan - IOS;
  hosts: ios
  tasks:
    - name: "Debug vars Take 2"
      debug:
        var=new_vlan_id
```

Comment: => `msg: "Creating vlan {{ vlanIdToAdd }}"` Note the space between the column ending the key name and the beginning of the value (which is missing in your example). `Hello world` is simply the default debug msg when none is found in the task.

Comment: @Zeitounator I have updated the question.  and modified my question with problem I have, the value is available in play but not in next play.  Do I have an issue with scope ? and how to solve it?

Comment: Vars prompt do not survive after the play. You will need to store the value somehow (e.g. using `set_fact`, storing it somewhere else...) to use it in the next play.

Comment: @Zeitounator question updated with your suggestion.  Could you please answer so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in my comment, `vars_prompt` are only available inside a given play as this is their scope. This is explained in [plabooks variable documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables)

From my suggestion, you have tried to use `set_fact`. As you will see in the same documentation, those vars are scoped to host and are only available while playing a task on host having the given fact. Meanwhile, you can access facts from other host using the [`hostvars` magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

Here is one way to work arround this kind of chicken-egg problem. It might not be exactly what you are looking for but will hopefully give you some ideas for your best solution. I tried to make it self explanatory.

The following `test.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Play dedicated to vars_prompt and storing facts in localhost
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: my_prompt
      prompt: enter a value
      private: no

  tasks:
    - name: store prompt in fact
      set_fact:
        my_prompt: "{{ my_prompt }}"

- name: Use fact on host a by directly calling it in a task
  hosts: a
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: display the fact
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].my_prompt }}"

- name: Use the fact on host b by first assigning to a play var
  hosts: b
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_prompt: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].my_prompt }}"

  tasks:
    - name: display the fact
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_prompt }}"
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i a,b, test.yml 
enter a value: toto

PLAY [Play dedicated to vars_prompt and storing facts in localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [store prompt in fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [Use fact on host a by directly calling it in a task] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [display the fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a] => {
    "msg": "toto"
}

PLAY [Use the fact on host b by first assigning to a play var] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [display the fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [b] => {
    "msg": "toto"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
a                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
b                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Meanwhile, if this is possible in your scenario, you can as well set the fact on all hosts in your inventory so as to reuse it anywhere, this makes a much simpler playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Play dedicated to vars_prompt and storing facts on all host (except implicit localhost)
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: my_prompt
      prompt: enter a value
      private: no

  tasks:
    - name: store prompt in fact
      set_fact:
        my_prompt: "{{ my_prompt }}"

- name: Use fact on host a
  hosts: a
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: display the fact
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_prompt }}"

- name: Use the fact on host b
  hosts: b
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: display the fact
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_prompt }}"

- name: Simple demo implicit localhost is not part of the all group and does not have the fact
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: show fact is undefined on localhost
      debug:
        var: my_prompt
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i a,b, test.yml 
enter a value: titi

PLAY [Play dedicated to vars_prompt and storing facts on all host (except implicit localhost)] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [store prompt in fact] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a]
ok: [b]

PLAY [Use fact on host a] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [display the fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a] => {
    "msg": "titi"
}

PLAY [Use the fact on host b] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [display the fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [b] => {
    "msg": "titi"
}

PLAY [Simple demo implicit localhost is not part of the all group and does not have the fact] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show fact is undefined on localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_prompt": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
a                          : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
b                          : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: if I used hosts: all for gathering values and then specific hosts would I not avoid this  hostvars['localhost'] ? if you look at the playbook I posted it works, I used all hosts when getting input and the saving it as a fact and when I run it I use a specific hosts and can access the value

Comment: If you look at my latest edit, you have all options.